# How to keep form items selected after post request.Using php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, html-select, multiple-select

I have a form where it contains 7 multiple select dropdowns. I need to keep them multiple options selected after the form is submitted to same page. I checked multiple threads, however, few explained about only single selected dropdowns. Please suggest me to keep the multiple options selected for many dropdowns. This form is developed on php.

```
<select name="selectAccount[]" multiple="multiple" class="multiple">

<option value="0" selected="selected">All</option>

<?php
$viewquery="select Account_Name from accounts";
$viewresult=  mysql_query($viewquery);
while($elements=  mysql_fetch_array($viewresult))
    {
       echo "<option value=\"".$elements['Account_Name']."\"";
       if(isset($_POST['selectAccount'])==$elements['Account_Name'])
       echo 'selected';
       echo ">".$elements['Account_Name']."</option>";

}
?>
</select>
```

If I use above code, all the options from the dropdown are selected. However I need to select only the options which are selected before submit. Please help.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question?

Comment: If You Want to do with PHP only Then It may be little lengthy. Why Don't You Use Ajax For This Purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the line

```
if(isset($_POST['selectAccount'])==$elements['Account_Name'])
```

Two things you might want to consider:
if you use a field like this

```
<select name="selectAccount[]" multiple="multiple" class="multiple">
```

then `$_POST['selectAccount']` will be an array, so you might want to check if `$_POST['selectAccount'`] is set and then if the array contains your `$elements['Account_Name']`
you can use **[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)** for that.

Comment: Aswesome.. Thanks smarques.. It worked like charm in my requirement. Thanks a lot.:)